# Chrome Javascript Extension - How do I open a page in a new tab w/o actually going to that tab?

Tags: javascript, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently writing an extension for Chrome (the way you can integrate jQuery etc is pretty awesome, just like greasemonkey) however I have stumbled upon a problem:

I would like to open a page in a new tab without actually focusing that tab (so stay on the same page)

Thanks!

Comment: right-click "Open link in new Tab".. or were you talking about programtically opening it?

Comment: This wouldn't be on StackOverflow if I weren't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://...", selected: false});
```

If you need this in a content script where Chrome Tab API isn't available, you need to send a [request](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html) to a background page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to blur and focus the window.

```
var winPop = window.open("blah.html");
winPop.blur();
window.focus();
```

Comment: no problem, this is still a pretty good idea, might be useful for scripts w/o the extension context :)